# Issue with Spring Data REST after adding dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am trying to configure my springboot application using spring Data REST. I am having challenges displaying data from my entity class with Spring-Data REST. I have added the necessary dependency to my pom.xml file but when I try to access the endpoints on the web browser or via postman, I get nothing.

See the Error message from web browser and postman:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 24 18:41:33 PDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Postman error message


{
{
  "timestamp" : "2020-03-25T01:13:38.867+0000",
  "timestamp" : "2020-
  "status" : 404,
  "error" : "Not Found",
  "message" : "No message available",
  "path" : "/api/employees"
}
```

Here is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dafe.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppLogger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AppLogger</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add dependency for Spring Data REST -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my entity class with name Employee

```
package com.dafe.spring.logger.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    // define fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;


    // define constructors

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    // define getter/setter

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    // define tostring

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is my EmployeeRepository interface

```
package com.dafe.spring.logger.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.dafe.spring.logger.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: ...assuming "default", try `/employees`.

Comment: I'm sure you still need to correctly configure your repositories. How are you configuring `EmployeeRepository`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the base uri from my application.properties file, I added `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` and it worked like magic

According to the documentation of Spring Data Rest, "by default, Spring Data REST serves up REST resources at the root URI, '/'. There are multiple ways to change the base path.

With Spring Boot 1.2 and later versions, you can do change the base URI by setting a single property in application.properties, as follows: `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` "

For more details of Spring Data REST, use this link: [Spring Data REST reference guide](https://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer is not for Spring Data REST users because apparently it automatically configures the mappings.

I do not see a mapping for /api/employees in the code that you posted.

Have you defined a method that is annotated with `@GetMapping("/api/employees")`?
It should be in a class that is annotated with `@RestController`.

```
@GetMapping("/api/employees")
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    // Get employees from EmployeeRepository
}
```

Comment: those are not needed when working with Spring-Data-REST on SpringBoot. The dependency configuration in my Pom.xml takes care of it. Please check my Pom.xml file above to see the dependency that handles what restcontroller class and service classes would be needed for in a normal Spring-JPA application.

Comment: Interesting. I need learn about that. What i noticed in the documentation is that the default base path is '/'. Have you configured it as  '/api'?

Comment: I just checked it out. Thanks for the clue.